# Fullscreen frame in Swing

Tags: swing, size, fullscreen, frame

With the command `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();`
I can get the screen size, but I don't know how to set this size in my frame.

I want to configure my frame to always be adjusted in the screen, regardless of screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want - fullscreen mode or just to maximize the `JFrame`.

Fullscreen exclusive mode is used for things like games or kiosk displays - your app is the only thing visible and able to be interacted with.  Here's a link to some [fullscreen exclusive mode documentation and tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html).

On the other hand, if you just want to maximize the `JFrame` this means that you still want the regular old "window inside the desktop" experience, just that the window is maximized to take up all the available desktop space.  In this case, you would just call the [setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29) on your `JFrame` right after you set it visible.

Comment: I want to set the fullscreen mode for my JFrame. You dont know the method "GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();" ?

Comment: if I put setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) when the user click in "maximize" button, the screen (frame) will be desconfigured again, I want to make the app configured for the two options, maximize or not